# How to add a simple paypal donate button to a Plone 4 site?

Tags: paypal, plone

I "assumed" I could add a simple PayPal "donate" button by pasting button html into a Static Text portlet. However, for security reasons,the html is auto stripped when I save the portlet. Can anyone tell me how I should go about adding a simple paypal donate button to a Plone 4 site?

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to *not* disable `safe_html` filtering. Just install [collective.portlet.embed](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.portlet.embed)

This way TinyMCE users and other static text portlet still keep HTML filtering (which is good).

Comment: Adding collective.portlet.embed solved my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your HTML button in PayPal there is a tab where you can switch to Email method and it will give you a basic URL link instead of an HTML form.  That URL could used in any link attached to text or an image.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the the "safe_html" transform thru ZMI: portal_transforms --> safe_html (`http://yourplonesite/portal_transforms/safe_html/manage_main`)

You can disable it generally, by setting `disable_transform` to `1`. 
Or IMHO better configure `nasty_tags`, 'remove_javascript', etc. to your needs.